# How do I list a column in a row in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let's assume that i have the following:
[image: prtsc]

I want to show that data in a table like that:
[image: prstc]

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
New Table = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'Table',
    'Table'[Column2],
    "Column1", CONCATENATEX('Table','Table'[Column1], "|")
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure like this:

```
 MyMeasure = CONCATENATEX(MyTable, MyTable[Column1], "|")
```